# SSH Tunneling on webServer, localhost:80 -> localhost:81, but I received Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I try to make a SSH Tunneling, localhost:80 -> localhost:81
I generate my keys localy and add the .pub on authorized_keys in the cloud.
But I received, Permission denied (publickey).
Ok, not the same key to access with root ( I put user@ip )
and already had a key on the server to authorize access to the terminal by "user"

As I understand it I need to create a new user if I don't want to use the same key. And even then I could not using the same existing key.

I also didn't know if it was meant to be
remote port forwarding
or
Dynamic port forwarding

Edit:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file from the server

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config 
shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options 
override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in 
future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in 
/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware 
issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account 
processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication 
will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run 
without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set 
PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

I tryng this command to tunneling: `ssh -R 81:localhost:80 ubuntu@localhost`
To encript data of port 80 and pass to port 81

Terminal response: `ubuntu@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Please share the actual ssh command you're using and the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file from the server. It may be blocking forwarding. It will also tell if there is something unusual on the pubkey auth configuration. Still, it seems to me that just using ssh-copy-id should solve this for you. Just search how to use this command.

Comment: It shows you have configured public key authentication incorrectly. Check permissions of `~/.ssh` (better set to 0700) and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote. Both should be owned by the user. Also if the key has non-default name locally, use `ssh -i private-key-file` for it to be used.

Comment: Editing completed. Note: I want to encrypt with my public key already added and configured on the server and decrypt on my computer. The key has been configured by the cloud server service

Comment: The problem is, the user `ubuntu` in your case should have the right to open privileged port (80). Since you doing this with localhost, it may be easier to reverse things: `ssh ubuntu@localhost -L 80:localhost:81` (under root). It essentially will do the same thing, but ssh client running as root will be certainly able to open port 80. In any case, check that simple `ssh ubuntu@localhost` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally understood behind the command.

I thought I needed to use ssh tunnel (the command) on the server, so I was getting the errors ok.

But the command was to be on the client. I didn't understand that everything is going to happen through ssh port 22. So... my service port
does not need to be exposed.

`ssh -L targetPort:localhost:webServerPort -C -N -l user server_ip`

this works, runnning in client. SSH use the 22 port to give me webServerPort info.